# Block user inputs on textarea Angular 6

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6, textarea

I have below `textarea`. (textarea is in a ngx-datatable with add row button. user can add new rows with textarea)

```
<textarea type="text" class="form-control"
(ngModelChange)="row.isModified = true;"
[(ngModel)]="row.description" id="{{'description' + rowIndex}}"
(keyup)="doSomething($event);"
name="description" maxlength="200" rows="1" cols="1"></textarea>
```

and typescript code for `doSomething` function is as below.

```
doSomething(event) {
    const lines = 5;
    let description = (<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById(event.target.id));

        let newLines = description.value.split("\n").length;

        if(event.keyCode == 13 && newLines > lines) {
            //console.log('user input limit reached');
            event.preventDefault();
            return false;           
        }
        else {
            //console.log('user input under limit');
        }
}
```

I need to restrict user input after limit reached. I used `event.preventDefault(); return false;`. But this didn't work for me.

How could I solve this?

Comment: is maxLength attribute not restricting?

Comment: You should process `(keydown)` instead of `(keyup)`. See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-iabzyx?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html).

Comment: @ConnorsFan Thanks for the answer. This works like charm.